# Android: OnClick/TouchListener on View not delegated to ImageButton/View inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I have a menu popup activity which contains some menu points to click. One menu entry has this pattern:

`menu entry text [IMAGE]`

If the user clicks on the text, the click listener works. If the user clicks on the `ImageView`, the listener does not work although the listener is set on the surrounding LinearLayout.
First of all I used an `ImageButton` instead of `ImageView`. But click listener is not invoked with both. I tried to add these attributes:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Does not work.
I tried an `onTouchListener` instead of an `onClickListener`, does not work either. Any ideas how to make the image clickable too? Here is the important part of the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/screen_menupopup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent_black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_sort_abc_asc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sort_abc_asc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/cookbook_sort_abc_asc"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/button_menu_item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_configbutton_item" />
        </LinearLayout>
    ....
```

Activity code:

```
View viewSortAsccending = findViewById(R.id.item_sort_abc_asc);
viewSortAsccending.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra(RequestCode.SORT_ORDER_ALPHABETICAL_ASC.toString(), true);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        menuItemContainer.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with LinearLayout viewSortAsccending = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_sort_abc_asc); and remove all the android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" in teh ImageView

Comment: put all the related code, some problems might lie in the "less important" lines.

Comment: Did you try to set `android:descendantFocusability

="beforeDescendants"` ? With this the ViewGroup (LinearLayout) will get focused before it's children

Comment: @Chol You are right, That's the solution. Post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with :

```
LinearLayout viewSortAsccending = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_sort_abc_asc);
```

and remove all the following parameters in the imageView:

`android:clickable="true" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

LinearLayout will handle the OnClick as expected.
But actually I don't know why if you don't cast the view to LinearLayout, the behavior is not the same? If someone have the answer, it will be nice to update this post.

Comment: I didn't cast it, because it is not needed for setting the listener and furthermore it saves computation time (because of the non existing cast)

Answer (score 0):

Change your XML of your Imageview to:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_menu_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:onClick="imageview_button"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_configbutton_item" />
```

Then change your activity-code to:

```
    public void imageview_button(View view) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra(RequestCode.SORT_ORDER_ALPHABETICAL_ASC.toString(), true);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    menuItemContainer.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
}
```

Works fine here!
Hope this helps.

Comment: In your case the ImageView is responsing on click, But he wants the LinearLayout to do it

Comment: @Edik This is not what I want. Alexander is right. Both should be clickable.

Comment: @AlexanderTumanin  I see, sorry for wrong answer. Please let me know if you figure it out.